# Org Mode | How can I multiply one column with another and sum the result?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

At the moment I have this chart that I'd like to calculate cost basis from of

```
| AGG | 0.000004 | 104.40 | 10/5/2018 |
| AGG | 2.675897 | 110.15 | 5/31/2019 |
| AGG | 0.054206 | 110.32 | 6/4/2019  |
| AGG | 0.742459 | 110.39 | 6/6/2019  |
| AGG | 0.365697 | 110.31 | 6/10/2019 |
| AGG | 0.161737 | 110.47 | 6/17/2019 |
|-----+----------+--------+-----------|
|     |       4. | 656.04 |           |
#+TBLFM: @>$2=vsum(@1..@-1)
#+TBLFM: @>$3=vsum(@1..@-1)
```

How can I multiply the 2nd column with the 3rd column and sum the result?

Comment: Where do you want to place the result, in a new column?

Comment: That would work yes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compute the dot product of two column (think full column as a vector)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837229/how-to-compute-the-dot-product-of-two-column-think-full-column-as-a-vector)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you multiply cols 2 and cols 3 and store the result in col 5, and then the last row of col 5 has the sum (i.e., summing row 1 to row n-1 in col 5):

```
#+TBLFM: $5 = $2*$3
#+TBLFM: @>$5 = vsum(@1..@-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `vsum(@1$2..@-1$2 * @1$3..@-1$3)`

Comment: Could you please provide some context or an explanation on why this answers to the OP's question?